# Handle consecutive numbers in a mobile number

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my react-native application, I wanted to validated mobile numbers. So I used google-libphonenumber library.

Now there is a requirement to avoid consecutive numbers in the mobile number.
eg: in singapore, there are 8 digits for mobile numbers without the country code. Here we should not have 7 consecutive numbers of the same number.

```
+65 81111111
```

this should be wrong.

How can I validate this with google-libphonenumber library? This is my validation code.

```
/** mobile with country code */
const mobileWithCode = (value: any) => {
  const regex = /^[+](\d){8,13}$/;

  if (regex.test(value)) {
    try {
      const phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
      const mobile = phoneNumberUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput(value, '');
      const phoneType = phoneNumberUtil.getNumberType(mobile);

      if (phoneType === PhoneNumberType.MOBILE) {
        console.log(PhoneNumberType.TOLL_FREE);
        return phoneNumberUtil.isValidNumber(mobile);
      }
      return false;
    } catch (err) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return false;
};
```

Comment: What are the exact rules? At the moment your question is very broad, please try to narrow it down

Comment: As an example, singapore mobile number have 8 digits without country code. That 8 digits should not contain 7 consecutive numbers with the same number.
83333333 should be wrong. 
83322423 should be correct.

Comment: Aren't you able to use another regex? You've already written one, so you could append a rule to it.

Comment: But that's only true for Singapore or other places? Say, if you have `+33 81111111` (France) would that be valid? What about `+44 81111111` (the UK) or `+49 81111111` (Germany)?

Comment: They should not be valid as for the requirement. I know it is weird, but that was the client requirement.

Comment: Kobe, can you suggest the regex for that?

Comment: @Shashika `/(\d)\1{6}$/`. This will return true if there are 7 consecutive numbers at the end

Comment: Thanks @Kobe, how can I check if the whole text has 7 consecutive numbers? Here we check the last 7 digits. Now I want to test the whole string.

Comment: Just remove the `$`

Comment: Thanks again. One last question, is it possible to set a dynamic value to (\d)\1{6} 6 here? (\d)\1{6}, here i want to set a variable for 6.

Comment: Sure, you'd have to use a template string here. The regex here is `match 1 digit, then check for 6 more of that same digit after`. So technically it's 7 - 1. You could rewrite the regex to be `const ex = \`/(\d)\1{${consecutive - 1}}/\``, where `consecutive` is 7

Comment: Don't know why, but react-native gives a syntax error for 
const consecutiveRegex = `/(\d)\1{${numberLength - 1}}/`;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198020/discussion-between-shashika-and-kobe).

Comment: @Shashika im on the chat now